# Mule Parentheses + Replacement Params in JDBC Queries Failing

Tags: jdbc, mule

I'm having trouble with Mule executing a JDBC query that works externally.  It fails once I put parentheses in it if it also has replacement parameters.  I'm wondering if MEL has some issues with parentheses that I don't understand.

The following (simplified) example executes correctly in my flow:

```
    <jdbc:query
        key="QueryStrategy"
        value="SELECT product_strategy FROM licensing.product WHERE product_sku = #[flowVars['productSku']] OR product_sku IS NULL"/>
```

If I replace the reference to a flow variable with a constant, I can add parentheses and it still works:

```
    <jdbc:query
        key="QueryStrategy"
        value="SELECT product_strategy FROM licensing.product WHERE (product_sku = 'Trial' OR product_sku IS NULL)"/>
```

However, the minute I add parentheses while the replacement parameter is present, I get an exception:

```
    <jdbc:query
        key="QueryStrategy"
        value="SELECT product_strategy FROM licensing.product WHERE (product_sku = #[flowVars['productSku']] OR product_sku IS NULL)"/>
```

The exception is shown below. Is this a problem with Mule's formatting of what it sends to Microsoft or some bug in the Microsoft JDBC driver?

**EDIT**
Here's the amended log with DEBUG turned on for org.mule.transport.jdbc.

```
com.ca.eai.esb.interceptor.EaiLoggingInterceptor FlowBefore | Flow Name: Main | MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS: /127.0.0.1:59952 | consumerTransId: E0acd42cb-100d-11e3-a264-852205c1b19e | consumerDateTimeSent: null | consumerApp: null | consumerUsername: null | mule.muleId: null | esbTransCode: null | messageSourceName: endpoint.https.localhost.8088.license.requests.r.v1 | currentTimestamp: 2013-08-28 14:09:55.309
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcConnector Borrowing a dispatcher for endpoint: jdbc://QueryStrategy
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcMessageDispatcher Connecting: JdbcMessageDispatcher{this=5764c302, endpoint=jdbc://QueryStrategy, disposed=false}
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcMessageDispatcher Connected: endpoint.outbound.jdbc://QueryStrategy
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcConnector Borrowed a dispatcher for endpoint: jdbc://QueryStrategy = JdbcMessageDispatcher{this=5764c302, endpoint=jdbc://QueryStrategy, disposed=false}
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcConnector Borrowed dispatcher: JdbcMessageDispatcher{this=5764c302, endpoint=jdbc://QueryStrategy, disposed=false}
org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.SelectSqlStatementStrategy Trying to receive a message with a timeout of 10000
org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.SelectSqlStatementStrategy SQL QUERY: SELECT product_strategy, product_id FROM licensing.product WHERE product_name = ? AND (product_sku is null OR product_sku = ? ) ORDER BY product_sku DESC, params = {My Product,My Product}
org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcConnector Returning dispatcher for endpoint: jdbc://QueryStrategy = JdbcMessageDispatcher{this=5764c302, endpoint=jdbc://QueryStrategy, disposed=false}
com.ca.eai.esb.interceptor.EaiLoggingInterceptor FlowLast | Flow Name: Main | MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS: /127.0.0.1:59952 | consumerTransId: E0acd42cb-100d-11e3-a264-852205c1b19e | consumerDateTimeSent: null | consumerApp: null | consumerUsername: null | mule.muleId: null | esbTransCode: null | messageSourceName: endpoint.https.localhost.8088.license.requests.r.v1 | currentTimestamp: 2013-08-28 14:09:55.791 | elapsedTime: 484ms
org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://QueryStrategy, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=Database
  lifecycle=start
  this=333d612e
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.QueryStrategy', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.(SQL Code: 0, SQL State: + null) (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException)
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:190 (null)
2. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. Query: SELECT product_strategy, product_id FROM licensing.product WHERE product_name = ? AND (product_sku is null OR product_sku = ? ) ORDER BY product_sku DESC Parameters: [My Product, My Product](SQL Code: 0, SQL State: + null) (java.sql.SQLException)
  org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner:540 (null)
3. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://QueryStrategy, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=Database
  lifecycle=start
  this=333d612e
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.QueryStrategy', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerParameterMetaData.<init>(SQLServerParameterMetaData.java:426)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1532)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Errors like this usually mean the syntax error occurs _before_ or at the text mentioned in the exception. That said I don't see anything obviously wrong with your query.

Comment: Can you set the logging level of org.mule.transport.jdbc to DEBUG so we can see what's the statement that's being sent?

Comment: Sure.  I'll edit the post above

Comment: They don't seem to be the same SQL command.

Comment: Oh, my bad!  I forgot that I simplified the query even more for the post here.  I've updated with a single query.

Comment: I have tried the following and it worked fine: <jdbc-ee:query key="foo" value="SELECT product_strategy FROM product WHERE (product_sku = #[flowVars['productSku']] OR product_sku IS NULL)" />. I ran it against SQL Server 2008 and I'm not sure about the driver's version but the jar is sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: That's unfortunate (that you can't reproduce it).  I'm also using sqljdbc4.jar on v4.0.  I guess I'll try different machines.  What version of Mule are you on?  I'm on 3.3.1.

Comment: I have tried with 3.3.1 too.